# How to prevent str to encode unicode characters as hex codes?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

When I `print` a unicode string in Python directly, I see a string with same characters that I have in my string. When I embed it into some container (put in a list, in a map, etc), `str` representation converts unicode characters to \uXXXX representation.
Interestingly, I can call a `print` on this container with a string, but cannot `print str` of a string itself (gives a UnicodeEncodeError).

Can I configure `str` to encode nested strings to UTF8 strings? Looking at this hex symbols makes debugging very painful.

Example:

```
>>> v = u"abc123абв"
>>> d = [v]
>>> print v
abc123абв
>>> print d
[u'abc123\u0430\u0431\u0432']
>>> print str(v)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec cant encode characters in position 6-8: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print str(d)
[u'abc123\u0430\u0431\u0432']
```

I'm using Python 2.7.6 on ubuntu and console encoding is UTF8. Python seems to use UTF8 as well:

```
>>> print(sys.stdout.encoding)
UTF-8
>>> print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
UTF-8
>>> print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
UTF-8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print [v]` calls `repr(v)` that returns ascii-printable characters as is and everything else is escaped using `\x`, `\u`, `\U`, ...

Remember an object such as `dict(a=1)` is different from its text representation (`repr(dict(a=1))`). Unicode string is an object too (`type(v) == unicode`) like any other and therefore `repr(v) is not v` (btw, `repr(repr(v)) is not repr(v)` too -- think about it).

To display human-readable text for debugging in Python console, you could provide custom `sys.displayhook` e.g., you could encode any (embedded) `unicode` object using `sys.stdout.encoding`. In Python 3, `repr(unicode_string)` returns Unicode characters that are printable in the current environment as is (characters that would cause `UnicodeEncodeError` are escaped).

`str(v)` raising `UnicodeEncodeError` is unrelated. `str(v)` calls `v.encode(sys.getdefaultencoding())` and therefore it fails for any unicode string with non-ascii characters. Do not call `str()` on Unicode strings (it is almost always an error), print Unicode directly instead.

Comment: Thank you for an informative answer. I did not realize ````repr```` is used in printing a container at all. So you basically say that I cannot change those escaped characters from ````print d```` into unicodes in Python 2 (while Python 3 will do it automatically), don't you?

Comment: @Osman-pasha As I said, if you want to change what is displayed in Python console: `>>> d` then set `sys.displayhook`. Use just `d` instead of `print d`

Comment: If it is not interactive then you could print the list however you like e.g., `print json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't change `str`, change your `way of thinking`.

If you need to print netsted element than get it from container and print it - don't print all container.

```
v = u"abc123абв"
d = [v, v, v]

print d[0]
# abc123абв

print ", ".join(d)
# abc123абв, abc123абв, abc123абв
```

---

btw: Python print hex code (and other elements) for testing/debuging reason.

When you see

```
[u'abc123\u0430\u0431\u0432']
```

you know: it is list (`[` and `]`) with unicode text (`u` and `'`) and there are non-ASCII chars in that text.