# Special caracters don't display correctly when splitting

Tags: python, text, encoding, text-files, special-characters

When I'm reading a line in a text file, like this one below :

```
présenté alloué ééé ààà tué
```

And try to print it in the terminal, it displays correctly. But when I apply a split with a space as separator, it displays this :

```
['pr\xc3\xa9sent\xc3\xa9', 'allou\xc3\xa9', '\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9', '\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa0', 'tu\xc3\xa9\n']
```

I just use this to read the text file :

```
f = open("test.txt")
l = f.readline()
f.close()
print l.split(" ")
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: The "\x" escape character means that the next two chars represent a hex value.  The first hex value of "\xc3\xa9", or c3a9, is the unicode value of "é", so your data is being preserved, just in hex format.  I'm not sure why the split method is doing that.

Comment: Because that's what the `list.str()` method does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent str to encode unicode characters as hex codes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723821/how-to-prevent-str-to-encode-unicode-characters-as-hex-codes)

Comment: You need to encode in utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing the list is not the same as printing its elements

```
s = "présenté alloué ééé ààà tué"
print s.split(" ")
for x in s.split(" "):
    print x
```

Output:

```
['pr\xc3\xa9sent\xc3\xa9', 'allou\xc3\xa9', '\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9\xc3\xa9', '\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa0', 'tu\xc3\xa9']
présenté
alloué
ééé
ààà
tué
```

Comment: I didn't try to print its elements. I believed the specials caracters will remain like \xc3 when using it. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: @Biopy the question is actually a duplicate and there is a more complete answer in [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33723821/2142055).

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3.* solution:**
All you have to do is to specify the encoding you wish to use

```
f = open("test.txt", encoding='utf-8')
l = f.readline()
f.close()
print(l.split(" "))
```

And you'll get

```
['présenté', 'alloué', 'ééé', 'ààà', 'tué']
```

**Python 2.* solution:**

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open("""D:\Source Code\\voc-git\\test.txt""", mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
l = f.read()
f.close()
for word in l.split(" "):
    print(word)
```

Comment: It says that the arguement "encoding" isn't recognized by open() function.

Comment: @Biopy Iv'e added an additional solution for your Python version